# Can this work as a waterproofing method?

Tags: arduino-uno

Im making my garden automated with temperature, humidity and soil temperature sensors. I want to be able to connect my Arduino Uno to a solar panel and keep it outside at all times. I dont want to have to remove it to water the plants. Could I cover it in clear nail polish to water proof it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use a weatherproof enclosure?

Comment: need access to changing the pins where cables are connected.

Comment: @Tech2025 And how would nail polish be better at that?

Comment: Use a LilyPad? They are washable. Might need to cut the power when watering the plants?

Comment: If you don't varnish the pin headers, those won't be water-proof. Just get an enclosure. Unrelated; please don't use an UNO for this. An Uno just pisses away power with it's usb-to-serial chip and very inefficient voltage regulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nail polish would work in general as a fair **conformal coating**. However, conformal coatings are not generally intended as waterproofing, but moisture or humidity resistance.

If you product is going to be regularly submerged or deluged with water, you are better off using a waterproof enclosure with a good watertight gland around the cable entrance.

Comment: Thanks. Im using the nail polish and it has worked great. No problems with anything. I've gone ahead and bought my self some Elegoo Uno's since they are so cheap and do the same.